# PHP json_encode - Same Code once delivers an Array and once an object

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am using the same code within two PHP- classes. I copied and pasted it.
In one class an Array is delivered to the JavaScript in which I use a copied/pasted piece of code, too and once an Object.

Here is the PHP- Code:

```
private $status_good = array('Status' => 'good');
private $status_fail = array('Status' => 'fail');

echo json_encode($this->status_fail);
```

And here is the JS/jquery- Code:

```
    $.post("./someclass.php",
       {
            code    :   this.code,   
            input   :   this.input
       },   
       function( data ){
          console.log("Data: ")
          console.log(data );
       }
```

Once the console says: `Data: {"Status":"fail"}`
In the other script:   `Data: Object { Status: "fail" }`

I am doing no UTF- manipulation nor any header- manipulation.
Please be so kind and tell me how this may happen with exactly the same code in different classes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are 100% sure there's nothing else going on that you don't show here?

Comment: Hello Jeff, the arrays are not manipulated in any way. In one PHP- class I check if an email is sent and in the other I check if the number of results of a database query is higher than 0. So the json_encoding starts if the email is not sent or the amount of db- results is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `dataType` argument to `$.post` and/or set Content-type header in the php.

$.ajax does a *"best guess"* at the data type being returned if it is not explicitly told what to expect and there is no header to help it decide.

It would appear that it is getting it right in the one case and parsing JSON and in the other it is treating it as text and returning a string to the callback.

```
$.post("./someclass.php",
   {
        code    :   this.code,   
        input   :   this.input
   },   
   function( data ){
      console.log("Data: ")
      console.log(data );
   },'json')
```

Comment: Hello charlietfl, that seems to have done the job. I added the dataType 'json' to the $.post. Now the answer is recognized as an object. Still seems a bit weird but it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not totally weird. You are sending json without proper content type header probably.

Comment: Apologies. I meant that because the code is exactly the same and reacts differently. Of course I understand what you told me. Many thanks again.